# How can I get a slide-in effect for Guake under 12.10?

Tags: compiz, guake

Evidently, in earlier releases of Ubuntu, an animation add-on plugin for Compiz called Skewer could be tweaked to get a slide-in/slide-out effect for opening and closing Windows. Alas, I discovered Guake while running Quantal, and Skewer is gone from the Compiz plugin packages provided in the official repos. Guake's really nice, but the fade/expand effect just feels wrong -- is there any way to get Skewer back, or is there some other plugin that'll do what I want?

Answer (score 1):

I found a great article about this in Fedora Forum:

http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=197409

Basically you do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-fusion-plugins-extra
```

Launch Compiz Configuration Settings Manager (CCSM), go to the *Effects* section, tick the box next to **Animations Add-On**, then click on **Animations**.

In *Animations*; under *Animation Selection*; for the *Open Animation* tab; click on **New**, then:

- Select **Burn** as your *Open Effect*
- Enter `900` for *Duration*
- Enter `(type=Normal) & name=guake` for *Window Match*
- Enter `fire_life=0.1, fire_particles=100, fire_size=0.1, fire_slowdown=0.1, fire_direction=1` in *Options*
- Click on **Close**

Move this item up to the second position with the **Up** button, then click on the first item in the *Animation Selection* list (which should be a catch-all *Glide 2* effect with certain exemptions), click **Edit** and add the exemption `&!(name=guake)` to the end of its *Window Match* entry.

Repeat this process for the *Close Animation* tab and you should then be all set!

Launch Guake and you should see it slide down from the Unity Panel at the top of the screen.

If like me, you find that this effect does not persist correctly over reboot and you end up with the default Burn effect (Guake appearing and disappearing in a burst of big flames) then just go back into CCSM, click on the **Animations Add-On** button, select *Burn* and set everything down to its lowest, selecting **up** for *Fire direction*. This will set the global defaults for *Burn*.

I hope this helps anyone. ;)

Comment: // , Seems a bit outdated, per https://askubuntu.com/questions/792374/sliding-animation-for-guake-under-16-04