# Sliding animation for Guake under 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz, guake

I know that there are a lot of posts about it, but the problem is that the methods of achieving it, described in all the posts I've found so far seem to be outdated. The methods I've seen so far utilized `burn` and `skewer` compiz effects which seem to be no longer maintained. Anyway, I can't see them in the list of available animations in compiz. Installing compiz plugins extra didn't add those animations too. What is the 'modern' way to make Guake slide-in under 16.04?